# Selenium between HTML tags

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

What's the best way to get all the HTML in a page that is created by Javascript to pass to BeautifulSoup?

I'm currently using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.co.uk")
html = browser.find_elements_by_id("html")
```

But "html" is always an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Selenium does pretty much everything that BeautifulSoup does-- you can even directly access and manipulate javascript-created objects.  the selenium bindings are not terribly different from the beautiful soup ones, either.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to pass the page source to Beautiful Soup from Selenium would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.co.uk")
html_source = browser.page_source
html = BeautifulSoup(html_source)
```

This way, the browser is loading the page, extracting the FULL html source and passing it to BeautifulSoup. The result can be parsed like any other Beautiful Soup object.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is not an id. It should instead be like this:

```
html = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("html")
```

since html is a tag.

The search you originally did would return all elements where the id has been set to "html". An example of an element that would be returned:

```
<p id="html">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Th id of that element is "html" and the tag name is "p".

Answer (score 2):

You could also use something like

```
html_source = browser.page_source
```

This a webdriver provided function call, precisely to collect the full source or "get all the html in a page"